# has_many :through Association working with one-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations

- rails 4.2
- ruby 2.1

I have two very basic models (product and tag) with has_many association through another model (taggings).

I have another model (category) with one-to-many connection with the aforementioned model (product).

**Question:**

How to show in view the **tag list** of products with a specific product's category?

*In other words*: Is it possible to list all tags from a particular category of product?

Models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  belongs_to :category, counter_cache: true
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :products, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :tag, counter_cache: :products_count
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way is `category_object.products.map(&:tags).flatten` . Can be improved. :)

category has many products and product has many tags. Mapping tags method on each product. Flatten to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `product_tags` association to the `Category` class:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :product_tags, -> { uniq }, through: :products
end
```

When you access the `product_tags` association, Rails will use a `SELECT DISTINCT` query so you won't end up with duplicate tags and the DB will eliminate duplicates.

If the above doesn't feel natural for your model, then you can also use the following (assuming `c` is a `Category` instance):

```
Tag.joins(:products).where(products: { category: c})
```

The DB query will be very similar to the other example.